# Is this the right way to have data populate multiple tabs using the storage API?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage, web-storage

I'm essentially trying to have data propagate in multiple tabs using [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). To give an example, this is what I mean [here](http://mdn.github.io/web-storage-demo/).

My behavior is as follows—upon page load I see the info which was retrieved from session storage and saved in localStorage.

However when I copy and paste the URL to a new window I don't get the link added to the page instead I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null
    at populateStorage (dashboard:464)
    at setValue (dashboard:469)
    at dashboard:482
    at dashboard:487
```

This is my code:

```
(function() {

    function getSessionStorage() {
        try {
            if (!!window.sessionStorage) return window.sessionStorage;
        } catch (e) {
            return e.error;
        }
    }

    function getLocalStorage() {
        try {
            if (!!window.localStorage) return window.localStorage;
        } catch (e) {
            return e.error;
        }
    }

    function populateStorage() {
        var string = String.prototype.toString.call(obj.profile.data.vanityName);
        local_storage.setItem('vanityName', string);
    }

    function setValue() {
        populateStorage();
        var val = local_storage.getItem('vanityName');
        return val;
    }

    var session_storage = getSessionStorage(),
        local_storage = getLocalStorage(),
        rep_info = document.getElementById('rep-info'),
        session = session_storage.getItem('ngStorage-getRepInfo'),
        obj = JSON.parse(session),
        your_avon_URL = 'https://youravon.com/';


    rep_info.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<a href="' + your_avon_URL + (setValue()) + '">youravon.com/' + (setValue()) + '</a>');

})();
```

Isn't this the right way to go about this? Extract from session storage and then save to localStorage to persist when you copy and paste the link into a new tab?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is new tab on same domain and subdomain?

Comment: Ok...seems that new tab = new session ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage Might need to do something like use postMessage api to communicate between tabs , or keep everything in localStorage. There are also localStorage events that might help